# Is hive.exec.parallel broken?

Tags: hadoop, hive

Apparently, there is a reason why `hive.exec.parallel` is `false` by default.
When I set it to `true` (as recommended by an answer to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20957799/hive-sql-coding-style-intermediate-tables/)), my process dies with this message:

```
MapReduce Jobs Launched:
Job 0: Map: 2  Reduce: 1   Cumulative CPU: 6.43 sec   HDFS Read: 556 HDFS Write: 96 SUCCESS
Job 1: Map: 1  Reduce: 1   Cumulative CPU: 3.15 sec   HDFS Read: 475 HDFS Write: 96 SUCCESS
Job 2: Map: 1  Reduce: 1   Cumulative CPU: 3.36 sec   HDFS Read: 475 HDFS Write: 96 SUCCESS
Job 3: Map: 1  Reduce: 1   Cumulative CPU: 2.19 sec   HDFS Read: 475 HDFS Write: 0 SUCCESS
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 15 seconds 130 msec
OK
normalized_keyword      pixel_id        count   sum_log events
Time taken: 72.419 seconds

...
14.98user 0.62system 1:16.79elapsed 20%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 851392maxresident)k
8inputs+2096outputs (0major+83271minor)pagefaults 0swaps
text: java.io.EOFException
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readShort(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Display$Text.getInputStream(Display.java:113)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Display$Cat.processPath(Display.java:81)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.processPaths(Command.java:306)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.processPathArgument(Command.java:278)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.processArgument(Command.java:260)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.processArguments(Command.java:244)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.processRawArguments(Command.java:190)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.run(Command.java:154)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell.run(FsShell.java:254)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell.main(FsShell.java:304)
```

No useful data is produced. `set hive.exec.parallel.thread.number=2` has no effect (same failure)

Suggestions?

EDIT: `hive --version` does not work, but when it starts, it prints

```
Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-4.4.0-1.cdh4.4.0.p0.39/lib/hive/lib/hive-common-0.10.0-cdh4.4.0.jar!/hive-log4j.properties
```

so, I guess, the version is `0.10.0`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this issue: I will also watch for it. Which version of hive are you using?

Comment: @javadba: how do I figure that out? `hive --version` does not work!

Comment: true it does not! you have to look at the jar/lib files - the version is baked in the filenames. Pretty surprising missing functionality there ;)

Comment: It fails when `hive.exec.parallel.thread.number` is set to 8? I believe its the default value and it work fine with it in my environment (not CDH).
Does it always fail even if only one job is executed? (like `select count(*) from sometalbe`).
Does it fail on non-mapreduce jobs like `select * from sometable`?

Comment: @dimamah: it did not fail on a `select count(*) from sometalbe`, producing the same results as with non-parallel `hive`. However, it did not create two jobs, just one.

Comment: Well it should create only one job as there is only one job so no parallelism is achieved. Does it fail when `hive.exec.parallel.thread.number` is set to 8? try execution `set hive.exec.parallel.thread.number=8;' and then running some job in parallel.